# configure spam assassin to delete all spam above a score domain wide and override individual settings

Tags: spamassassin

Okay, so this is my scenario and what I want to try and do.  I maintain a Red Hat email server running qmail and spamassassin.  I have a domain that has well over 100 email account each with individual settings for spam scores and, whether or not to delete email incoming mail deemed spam.  What I want to accomplish is to change all those email email accounts to say a more stringent spam score value, AND to enable the deletion of email immediately as it flagged as such, for EACH AND EVERY email box. In short, I want to be able to override a user's individual settings spam settings, with my own.

Short of tediously going into each and every email box one by one, is there an way to do this all in one fell swoop?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to do it with qmail, but it's mail delivery agent probably has filtering capabilities. I run a Courier server at home with maildrop, and maildrop's system filter tosses everything with a score over 10 in /dev/null. The user's individual settings then filter it further.

Answer (score 1):

SpamAssassin does not delete mails, it only classifies them.

To delete (or reject) mails depending on that classification (even with per-user thresholds and policies) use an interface like [amavisd-new](http://www.ijs.si/software/amavisd/).

Answer (score 0):

You can override user configurations (user_prefs) with a site wide config (local.cf)

http://spamassassin.apache.org/full/3.0.x/dist/doc/Mail_SpamAssassin_Conf.html